What happens to the electric field in an accelerated capacitor?
Say we have a charged capacitor with some charge $Q$ in one of its plates (and of course the opposite charge on the other plate). It is a well-known result that the electric field inside this capacitor will be $\vec E = \frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0}\vec e_z$. What would happen to this field if we were to accelerate the capacitor? The charge on the plates would not change since charge is conserved, but accelerated charges emit radiation. Therefore, would the electric field inside the capacitor be altered in any way?
